# MonoMac WebView - Show Console or Web Inspector?

Tags: c#, webview, xamarin, monomac

Trying to figure out how to show the webkit console or inspector from a MonoMac application. It looks like it can be done in Objective-C by setting WebKitDeveloperExtras.

```
[USER_DEFAULTS registerDefaults:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject: 
[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"WebKitDeveloperExtras"]];
```

How can I set WebDeveloperExtras in MonoMac.WebKit.WebView?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
var defaults = NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults;
defaults.SetBool (true, "WebKitDeveloperExtras");
defaults.Synchronize();
```